# Why do you have to use require and call a function in one step in Node?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Using the socket.io example as my example:

Why does this work in node:

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

But doing it in two different steps does not? (i.e.):

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(server);
```

Comment: both work with node , any error?

Comment: In the first code, `io` gets set to the result of the `listen` call, not the `require`.

Comment: @trquoccuong  That's what I thought.  There error is `TypeError: io.on is not a function `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Here, `io` gets set to the result of calling `listen(server)` from the `socket.io` module.

Case 2:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(server);
```

Here, `io` gets set to the `socket.io` module itself.

So they perform the same function, but `io` ends up set to different values.

The chaining of function calls as seen in case 1 is a common idiom in node.js, but if you really want to use two lines while having `io` still end up set as it is in case 1, just capture the result of the `require` call separately:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io = socketio.listen(server);
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep them on separate lines (as with the rest of my node code) or do they have to be set up such as this?

Comment: `var sio = require('socket.io'); var io = sio.listen(server);` There, two lines.